# Not understanding why I need to unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't understand why I have to call the `unsubscribeFromAuth()` in `componentWillUnmount`.

At line 11 I declare a variable `unsubscribeFromAuth = null`. Then I assigned `auth.onAuthStateChanged` to it in `ComponentDidMount` at line 21. Then at line 27 I call `unsubscribeFromAuth()` in `componentWillUnmount`.

I know how `componentWillUnmount` works, but I am not able to understand this particular scenario.  Can someone explain this?

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header/header.component';
import { auth } from './firebase/firebase.utils';
import Homepage from './pages/homepage/homepage.components';
import ShopPage from './pages/shop/shop.component';
import SignInAndSignOut from './pages/sign-in-and-sign-out-page/sign-in-and-sign-out-page.component';

class App extends React.Component {
  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;  // line 11

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUser: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => { // line 21
      this.setState({ currentUser: user });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth(); // line 27
  }

  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Header currentUser={currentUser} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInAndSignOut} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Without unsubscribing, when the component is unmounted, changes to the auth state will continue to trigger `setState` calls. This will lead to warnings about it being a "no-op" since you can't set state on a component that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: sorry to say, But I don't get it yet, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) accepts an function to act an *observer for changes to the user's sign-in state*.

In other words, like you probably are already aware, the function you pass will get called every time a user signs in or out etc...

Once your component no longer exists anymore (unmounts), you don't need to keep getting updates about the sign-in changes. In fact, your function can't even run correctly anymore because the `this` in `this.setState` is the component that no longer exists.

If you do nothing about this, React will complain in the console with the message (if the function gets triggered):

> Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.

To solve this warning/error, you simply need to tell firebase that you no longer need to receive these updates by calling the returned [unsubscribe function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#optional-completed:-firebase.unsubscribe).

Calling this just informs firebase to stop using the function you provided if the auth state happens to change again.